# how to set iconBadge in BB10 webworks

Tags: push-notification, blackberry-webworks, notifyicon

When we receive Push Notifications in BB10 webworks application i am getting splat icon on MY Application home screen icon but How to set IconBadge with number of unread messages.

Answer (score 0):

WebWorks used to have a `blackberry.app.setHomeScreenIcon` method, however it was for the older BlackBerry OS 5.0+ platform, not BB10:
https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/gold/blackberry.app.html#.setHomeScreenIcon

Developers used to customize the icon at runtime (e.g. switch the default home-screen icon to one with a splat + number in the top right).

Unfortunately, the capability for an app to change its home screen icon is not available in BlackBerry 10.  Nor is there an API to display a custom splat with a number superimposed on it.